# Implement fuse.js.io function

Tags: javascript, html, search

all. I am trying to implement the fuse.js.io search function from, well, fuse.js.io. I have already linked the **fuse.js** to my HTML as well as a **search.js** with the variables:

```
    var list = [   {
    title: "The Adventures Of Huckleberry Finn",
    author: {
      firstName: "Mark Twain",
    }
 },];
```

The script, from Fuse, that is in my HTML is as followed:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
    var options = {
       shouldSort: true,
threshold: 0.6,
location: 0,
distance: 100,
maxPatternLength: 32,
minMatchCharLength: 1,
keys: [
"title",
"author.firstName"
]
};
var fuse = new Fuse(list, options); // "list" is the item array
var result = fuse.search("");


</script>
```

**Question:**

How do I link the **search.js** that contains:

```
    var list = [   {
    title: "The Adventures Of Huckleberry Finn",
    author: {
      firstName: "Mark Twain",
      }
    },];
```

to my HTML as an actual search feature that returns keys. Also, there are no console errors I just don't know how to turn the scripts into a real feature.

Answer (score 1):

Simply import it into your html like so

`<script src='path/to/script'></script>`

or you can require it in your current script tags like so

```
<script>
require('path/to/file')
... your code here ...
</script>
```

Update:
To include external scripts in your html you need to do so inside the  tag like so

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' ... ... ... // and so on
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuse.js/3.0.4/fuse.min.js'></script>
    <script src='path/to/your/own/js/file'></script>
  <head>
  <body>
    ... your html goes here. 
    You can also include <script> tags 
    in your html. The Load order is important so remember to 
    load your libraries (fuse.js) in the <head> so you have access 
    to it in the body
  <script>
    // javascript goes here 
    let something = 'this is fine for including js in your html'
    // OR if you want to create a separate file you can include it like so
    require('path/to/file')
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A follow up by "...your code here" do you mean all the code I wish to search using the script or the script code itself?

Comment: you put the require inside the code you've already got. That will load your search script into the same file as everything else

Comment: Regarding the import  option for your first answer in my HTML <head> I have both  <script src="fuse.min.js"></script> and <script src="search.js"></script>

Comment: Furthermore in the HTML in the body I have                                     
 <script type="text/javascript">

var options = {
  shouldSort: true,
  threshold: 0.6,
  location: 0,
  distance: 100,
  maxPatternLength: 32,
  minMatchCharLength: 1,
  keys: [
    "title",
    "author.firstName"
]
};
var fuse = new Fuse(list, options); // "list" is the item array
var result = fuse.search("");


</script>

Comment: Correct. you want to use absolute path though. ```<script src='./search.js'...```

Comment: That all depends on how you feel about it. the absolute path is with the dot slash ```./path``` that means "from this folder here... The other way (without the dot slash) look in different places depending on your environment.

Comment: Ok here is the pen, it's my first time using it, and I'll be online to correct errors https://codepen.io/kermittd/pen/eEMJmx

Comment: Cool. So... first off. You're gonna wanna import that fuse.min.js file via a CDN. Remove the minified js version from the js portion of the codepen and add this to your html <head> tag ```<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuse.js/3.0.4/fuse.min.js'></script>```

Comment: ok got it and just implemented that. Just to be clear I am trying to use fuse to return book searches.

Comment: i just updated my answer here for more clarity. Also, in codepen, your js file is automatically loaded into the html... this doesn't really help with your question (it just occurred to me). Get that pen as far as you can and then i'll fork it and make it work.

Comment: Ok just saw it I implemented it however now I also have a "GET" in my console for the external js

Comment: Yup. This is the http GET request for the library. You can actually add external libraries via the "settings" of the codepen there is a tab for you to add your libraries there to keep your html code cleaner. I've gotta hit the sack tonight but i'll check back with ya tomorrow and see what you've got. have a good night mang.

Comment: So does it take additional time to "GET" or is there additional steps I need to take